# How to get location of server based on IP address in Python

Tags: python, html, server, location

Can we program (probably in python) to get the server location from where we are accessing the webpage.

P.S. Its just for fun and to get in-depth knowledge.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an example of fetching server location using one of the APIs.

There are many others site options such as [keycdn](https://tools.keycdn.com/geo), [iplocation](https://www.iplocation.net/) and more.

```
import json
import urllib.request

GEO_IP_API_URL  = 'http://ip-api.com/json/'

# Can be also site URL like this : 'google.com'
IP_TO_SEARCH    = '87.250.250.3'

# Creating request object to GeoLocation API
req             = urllib.request.Request(GEO_IP_API_URL+IP_TO_SEARCH)
# Getting in response JSON
response        = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
# Loading JSON from text to object
json_response   = json.loads(response.decode('utf-8'))

# Print country
print(json_response['country'])
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use GeoIP tools like [this](https://www.ultratools.com/tools/geoIp) to get the location from the IP address. It's not 100% accurate but usually it's close enough.

There are also python modules such as [GeoIP](https://pypi.org/project/GeoIP/) and [python-geoip](https://pypi.org/project/python-geoip/) which do basically what you want. If you want the most accurate results you need to buy more accurate database from MaxMind.

Comment: Okay!!!
Thanks for the information, it would be better if you would have suggested me some lines of code. :)

Comment: Updated answer to include a python module which does the same thing. @PrasunParate

Answer (score 0):

You can use bin file to lookup the IP address information. For instance, using IP2Location Python library and IP2Location Lite bin file:

```
import IP2Location
 
IP2LocObj = IP2Location.IP2Location()

IP2LocObj.open("IP2LOCATION-LITE-DB11.BIN")
rec = IP2LocObj.get_all("8.8.8.8")
 
print rec.country_short
print rec.country_long
print rec.region
print rec.city
print rec.isp
print rec.latitude
print rec.longitude
print rec.zipcode
print rec.timezone
```

You can get the IP2Location Lite database from here: https://lite.ip2location.com/ip2location-lite